# Добавление приставок к глаголам перемещения

Tags: глаголы, словообразование, приставки

Рассмотрим в качестве примера пару глаголов «везти — возить». Я встречал упоминания, что эти формы называются «Imperfective definite» и «Imperfective indefinite» соответственно (не знаю, насколько это правда). Допустим, я хочу добавить приставку «пере-».

Я повспоминал разные глаголы и составил вот такую таблицу:

```
плыву   плаваю      —   переплываю
бреду   брожу       —   перебредаю

иду     хожу        —                     перехожу
еду     езжу        —                     переезжаю
везу    вожу        —                     перевожу
тащу    таскаю      —                     перетаскиваю
```

Как видно, в некоторых случаях используется первая форма, в некоторых — вторая. Такое впечатление, что вторая форма за основу берется чаще (я, кажется, знаю ещё одно слово, относящееся к первой группе, но не хотел бы пока его упоминать, поскольку с ним всё ещё сложнее).

Почему так? Чем это регулируется?

Comment: Есть ощущение, что здесь влияет звонкая или глухая согласная участвует в последнем слоге. Для звонкой вроде `з` используется `ж`, а для глухих - исходный вариант. Например `переколоть дрова`. Но общего правила скорее всего нет, например `брить` и `брею`

Comment: «переколоть» это совершенный вид. Мне всё-таки надо было в вопросе уточнить, что вид глагола-то меняться не должен. Кроме того эти два типа глаголов (первый и второй столбец) бывают-то только у глаголов перемещения, да и то не у всех. К чему пример с «брить» и «брею», я не понял, честно говоря.

Comment: Ок, перемещения так перемещения.

Comment: Ок, перемещения так перемещения. Только вот перечислить все глаголы перемещения и выделить их в отдельную категорию на основании каких-то формальных признаков я, к сожалению, не в состоянии. По крайней мере с точки зрения словообразования ... Пожалуй, оставлю возможность ответить на этот вопрос кому-нибудь более проницательному :)

Comment: Просто в качестве источника вдохновения относительно слов с `ПЕРЕ-` оставлю здесь эту ссылку: http://vidahl.agava.ru/W143.HTM

Comment: It's not as easy as you think. Shortly speaking, you can add this prefix to any of these words (e.g. перейду, перееду, перевезу, перетащу) but there are some problems. For example. There are брести, бредать and бродить that results in перебрести, перебредать and перебродить. Also. You wrote ехать, ездить and переезжать (пере+езжать). Next. Переплывать is formed by connection пере and плавать (by historical reasons плавать with prefixes changes to плывать). And so on, a lot of little nuances that only linguists can explain right. I'm not a linguist unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Одна из проблем, которая бросается в глаза: слева взято настоящее время глаголов, хотя стоило бы взять неопределённую форму. По пути от левого столбца до правого происходит подмена, изменяется суффикс или корень, и по неопределённой форме эта подмена более заметна. Если взять неопределённую форму, получатся такие слова:

плыть, плавать, переплыть, переплавать, переплывать (переплывать можно реку, а переплавать — это слишком долго находиться в воде)
брести, бродить, побрести, побродить (взял другую приставку, иначе слова странные по смыслу получаются)
идти, ходить, отойти, отходить, отхаживать
ехать, ездить, заехать, заездить, заезжать
везти, возить, отвезти, отвозить
тащить, таскать, перетащить, перетаскать, перетаскивать

Разные времена глаголов — это одна сторона вопроса, а разные корни и суффиксы — это другая сторона.

Кстати, про приставки и совершенные виды. Меня в школе учили трём временам, но [есть мнение, что стоит выделять четыре](http://language.ucoz.ru/str4.html).